# Counting number of vowels and consonants in a string

Tags: c, string

I keep on getting a [Linker error]C:\Users etc and collect2: Id returned 1 exit status code errors on my program but I don't see anything wrong with it. This is my program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main (){
int vowels = 0, cnsnts = 0;
int i, length;
char string[100];

printf("Enter sentence:");
gets(string);
length = strlen(string);

for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
    switch(toUpper(string[i])){
        case 'A':
            vowels++;
            break;
        case 'E':
            vowels++;
            break;
        case 'I':
            vowels++;
            break;
        case 'O':
            vowels++;
            break;
        case 'U':
            vowels++;
            break;
        default:
            cnsnts++;
    }
}

printf("The number of vowels are %d.\n", vowels);
printf("The number of consonants are %d.\n", cnsnts);

system("pause");
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Spaces are not vowels or consonants.

Comment: @Ghost along with all non-alphanumerics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
toUpper(string[i])
```

to

```
toupper(string[i])
```

add `<ctype.h>` header and turn on your compiler warnings.

Comment: woah thanks it's working now. that was such a lame mistake. sorry for disturbing

Answer (score 1):

First add

```
#include <ctype.h>
```

then change the camel case [toUpper](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/toupper/) like so

```
toupper(string[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

You must `#include <ctype.h>` and have mistakenly capitalized the `u` in `upper`.  Your switch could also stand to be brought down a bit

```
switch(toupper(string[i])) {
    case 'A':
    case 'E':
    case 'I':
    case 'O':
    case 'U':
        vowels++;
        break;
    default:
        cnsnts++;
}
```

This style takes advantage of fall-throughs.  If a case doesn't end with a `break` (or `return`, `continue`, or `goto`) it will enter the case below it.  This continues until a control flow altering keyword is hit.  The switch above is functionally equivalent to your original, but a lot shorter.

You might also consider checking that `string[i]` is a letter at all with `isalpha` before the `switch`

```
if (!isalpha(string[i])) continue;
```